# Get account locked status using LDAP and VBScript without binding to the user object

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to get the locked status of Active Directory accounts without having to bind to them using VBScript.  This query is also across multiple domains.  I have found an LDAP attribute lockoutTime but can't get it to work properly.

```
Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2

Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE

strFilter = "(&(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName=userid))"
strAttrib = "distinguishedName,userAccountControl,pwdLastSet,lockoutTime"
strQuery = "<GC://dc=domain,dc=com>;" & strFilter & ";" & strAttrib & ";subtree"

objCommand.CommandText = strQuery
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute

If objRecordSet.RecordCount > 0 Then
    If objRecordSet.Fields( "lockoutTime" ) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Account locked"
    Else
        MsgBox "Account not locked"
    End If
End If
```

The lockoutTime field is null unfortunately.  I found the below code too but this doesn't help either as the lockoutTime field is null regardless if the user is locked out or not as I tested it out on a currently locked out user acount and a user account that is not locked.

```
Set objLockout = objRecordSet.Fields( "lockoutTime" )
If objLockout.lowpart = 0 And objLockout.highpart = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Account not locked"
Else
    MsgBox "Account locked"
End If
```

The reason I don't want to bind to each account is that it slows down the script considerably and I am doing this in conjunction with a classic ASP site.  I currently have a site that uses a query to bind to each account and then tested a site that just uses the LDAP query and when using just the LDAP query it is considerably faster.

Comment: There's a great script that exports locked out users, you might be able to glean something from it. [Find and Export Locked-Out AD Users with VBScript](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2014/03/Find-and-Export-Locked-Out-AD-Users-into-CSV-in-VBScript.html), the bit you are interested in is `lockoutFlag = adoRecordset.Fields("msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed").Value`.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that attribute but everything I read about it says that you have to bind to the user account to get it.  Gonna try it though as the script you pointed to uses it in the LDAP query.

Comment: Ok, tested.  You can use that attribute but only with LDAP.  It is not stored in the global catalog so I can't query other domains to get that info.